# why i cant get ID the same way I get any element from mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I have my User table in MongoDB [name,username,email,password,roles]
Th value of email was decoded and now I am trying to get name,username and id but when I console log the id it keeps saying undefined.

```
axios
        .get(`http://localhost:8080/api/auth/users/${decoded.email}`)
        .then((res) => {
          setUserName({
            nameU: res.data.name,
            surName: res.data.surname,
            id: res.data._id,
          });
          const init = userName.nameU.charAt(0) + userName.surName.charAt(0);
          setAvatar({ initials: init });
          // console.log(localStorage);
          // console.log(sessionStorage);
          console.log(userName.id);
        })
```

also I made a usestate with name,surname and id and this is userName.

Comment: Can you provide more information such as a sample document and details about what the value of the variables in this code are? Also are you looking for `_id` rather that `id` by chance?

Comment: yes, i am looking for _id, for the id of the user. This is a sample of entry from compass:_id
648395e2399eaef99a15ef57
name
"Miru"
surname
"Neaga"
email
"miru@itinero.com"
password
"$2a$08$ofDPq7dxQqcUvHNqtExJQuNkVSqP8sVa4.G0qRsO2eWK7o5SSaSoG"

roles
Array

Comment: in compass, the _id is stored as Object_Id(648395e2399eaef99a15ef57). Maybe I need to get the _objectId instead of _id? I'm sorry but I am new to Mongo and code in general, this is for my thesis application

Comment: What _is_ `userName` here in this code though? Does it have a `id` field? Does it instead have a `_id` field? Can you log `userName` and share the results?

Comment: const [userName, setUserName] = useState({
    nameU: "",
    surName: "",
    id: "",
  });     and the result if Miru Neaga and undefined